# Async task completed abruptly. Debug View shows thread is stopped at Threadpoolexecutor.runWorker(ThreadpoolExecuter$Worker) line:1094

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to fetch Oauth token using GoogleAuthUtil.getToken and running the task as a separate thread using Async Task.

LogCat ouput shows me that the arguments required by the Async Task has been passed to it.(in this case the context, email and scope).

Here's the code of Async Task:

```
public class GetUsernameTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    Activity mActivity;
    String mScope;
    String mEmail;

    GetUsernameTask(Activity activity, String Email, String Scope){

        Log.i(TAG,"Local variables are set from received arguments");

        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mScope = Scope;
        this.mEmail = Email;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {                   
            Log.i(TAG,"fetchToken is called");
            String token = fetchToken();                                                            
                mToken = token;
                //Stuff to do with the token comes here - (Consider sending it to the backend;
            } catch(IOException e){

            }

            return null;
        }
```

LogCat also tells me that fetchToken() method is called. Here's the code for fetchToken()

```
private String fetchToken() throws IOException {

    try {                   
        Log.i(TAG,"attempts to getToken");

        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException){                    
        Log.i(TAG,"recoverable Exception Found");
        //((MainActivity) mActivity).handleException(userRecoverableException);                 
    } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException){                   
        Log.i(TAG,"fataException found");                   
    }

    return null;
}
```

The last logcat message before the debug mode opens up, is from  **Log.i(TAG,"attempts to getToken");**  .

I have no idea how to proceed from here or how to do debugging in this particular case. Any direction on where to go next will be great.

Comment: You need to form a question for us to help.  Are you seeing "fataException found" or "recoverable Exception Found" if not what do you expect to happen next?

Comment: Thanks @JohnVint for the comment. Both of these errors din't show up. The last logcat message was "attempts to get Token". Eclipse then asks me to open view in Debug mode. There I find that the value for completedAbruptly is true. Am not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: Since the debugger is stopped, it is going to throw an exception and it should has stopped just after that - in you case, at the line 1094 of that class. So, try to press the play button on debug view or the shortkey F8 - which also means play. It will walk through till logcat shows more useful info

Comment: @RmK Add a `catch(RuntimeException ex){` and print that stacktrace to logcat.  You may be observing an uncaught exception.

Comment: @JohnVint RuntimeException printed useful data. I had forgot to add a meta-data tag in the manifest file. Thanks.

Comment: @RmK You're welcome.  The tell-tale sign was what Plinio.Santos eluded to.  If a random break hits that you didn't set it usually means an unacaught runtime exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a meta-data tag missing in the android manifest file. I added the followin code in the manifest file

```
<meta-data 
            android:name = "com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
            />
```

The error was pointed out after I had added RuntimeException which printed the suggestion. Here's the code I added for RuntimeException

```
catch (RuntimeException e){

                  Log.i(TAG, "RuntimeException caught");
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
```